# How do I declare and call this activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have a special activity(this activity is not in the declared package in `AndroidManifest.xml`), it like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rtk.mediabrowser"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


        <activity android:name="com.skyworth.mediabrowser.media.NewMediaBrowser" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard" android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NewMediaBrowser" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

this `AndroidManifest.xml` is simplified by me, you can see, my declared package is `com.rtk.mediabrowser`, but my activity is in package `com.skyworth.mediabrowser.media`.

When I use code like this to call this activity, it can not find this activity:

```
componetName = new ComponentName("com.rtk.mediabrowser",
            "com.skyworth.mediabrowser.media.NewMediaBrowser");
```

Do I must move the activity to `com.rtk.mediabrowser`? or my code is something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think ComponentName need "action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" ".

Please add this code "intent-filter".

Comment: I said that I have simplified this `AndroidManifest.xml`, I add `action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"` in another activity

Answer (score 0):

```
componetName = new ComponentName("com.skyworth.mediabrowser.xxx",
        "com.skyworth.mediabrowser.media.NewMediaBrowser");
```

=>

```
componetName = new ComponentName("com.skyworth.mediabrowser.xxx",
        "com.skyworth.mediabrowser.meida.NewMediaBrowser");
```

It will work, Did you find the different ? **meida** spelling error

Comment: soryy, it is just I type wrong, the problem does exists.